# Unable to show replies in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

So I am in the process of building a forum and everything seems to work except viewing the reply. When I go to visit the page, it says that the method is undefined. Since my replies are on my discussion show action, I know that the following line is the issue:

```
@posts = @discussion.posts
```

In my view, I use @posts.reply but that fails. I've checked in the console and the user_id and discussion_id are correct via the post so I am unsure what is wrong. As mentioned, I think I am incorrectly calling the post with the code above? If not, then please let me know what code (if any) you would like to see and I can place it up for you.

Thank you!

Joe

```
#Post Model (Replies)

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :discussion
    belongs_to :user
end

#Discussion Model (Thread)

class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :posts
    extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :subject, use: :slugged
end

#User Model

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :articles
    has_many :discussions
    has_many :posts, :through => :discussions
    ...

#Discussions Controller to SHOW Posts

class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController

...
    def show
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @posts = @discussion.posts
    render :layout => 'discussion'
  end
...
end

#Posts Controller

class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_discussion, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  def new
    @post = @discussion.post.new
  end

  def create
    # new does not insert the record into the database
    @post = @discussion.posts.build(create_params)
    @post.user = current_user  
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @discussion, notice: "It has been posted!" 
    else
      render :new # or redirect back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = @discussion.posts.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash.notice = "Deleted"
    redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion)
  end

  private    

  def create_params
    # Only permit the params which the user should actually send!
    params.require(:post).permit(:reply) 
  end

  # Will raise an ActiveRecord::NotFoundError
  # if the Discussion does not exist
  def set_discussion
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:discussion_id])
  end
end

#View for showing Replies

<%= @posts.reply %>
Posted: <%= @posts.created_at.strftime("%b. %d %Y") %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Delete Comment", [@posts.discussion], data: {confirm: "Are you sure you wish to delete?"}, method: :delete %></p>

#View for Reply Form

<h2>Reply</h2>
<%= form_for [ @discussion, @posts ] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :reply, "Reply" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :reply %>
  </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Errors:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
(Highlighting the post form)

undefined local variable or method `posts' for #<#<Class:0x007fa71bd31228>:0x007fa721e5f018>
(Highlighting `<%= posts.reply %>`)
```

Comment: Show us your models and associations and the code on view for displaying messages. No one can help without that.

Comment: Sure thing, will add now. I will also add that an error is appearing to even leave a reply now.

Comment: Just update the information and if more if needed, please let me know. I could add the controllers

Comment: Just added both into the post =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
<%= @posts.reply %>
Posted: <%= @posts.created_at.strftime("%b. %d %Y") %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Delete Comment", [@posts.discussion], data: {confirm: "Are you sure you wish to delete?"}, method: :delete %></p>
```

should be like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    Posted: <%= post.created_at.strftime("%b. %d %Y") %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Delete Comment", [post.discussion], data: {confirm: "Are you sure you wish to delete?"}, method: :delete %></p>
<% end %>
```

But there are more errors in your code it seems which you will need to fix.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you that did solve one problem, silly me. The other issue is still there.

Comment: The second one? `undefined local variable or method posts` because there is no `posts` it is `@posts` and the `@posts` is also a collection so directly nothing will work on it you need to take its first, last or each element in loop.

Comment: No, the first one. Your solution helped the second one, thank you. The to_key is the issue now.

Comment: Correct this `<%= form_for [ @discussion, @posts ] do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for @discussion.post do |f| %>` and try.

Comment: undefined method `post' for #<Discussion:0x007fa71967a5f8> is given.

Comment: Sorry my bad it should be `@discussion.posts.build`

Comment: I have that defined within my controller (@post = @discussion.posts.build(create_params)) and I even try that but it throws up another error =P `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Comment: Did you try `<%= form_for  @discussion.posts.build do |f| %>`. The first argument is `nil` because that is defined in `create` action and you are on different action.

Comment: I did try that but that throws an error with posts_path, which I have the replies on the discussion page, not on a page of its own. My routes are resourceful just an FYI too. Error: undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa72377e2d8>:0x007fa71f2a6048>. PS: Thank you VERY much for taking the time to help me =)

Comment: So do you have `resources :posts` in your routes? If no add that

Comment: Yes, it is nested within the discussion routes. Did you want to move this to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84710/discussion-between-joe-dayvie-and-deep).